# How i can iterate list to get 10 elements each time in java

Tags: java, mysql, list

I have a list with 70 elements.

For Example:

`List<Long> dbList = new ArrayList<Long>();`

`dbList` has 70 records. If I send all the records to a query in MySql it takes a long time. So now I want to send each time 10 elements to database query. So I need to iterate over the list in intervals of 10. How can I do this? Is this a good approach to avoid long time when using `IN`.

**SQL Query**

```
select model.boothId, model.panchayat.panchayatId
from Table1 model
where model.panchayat.panchayatId in(:locationValues)
  and model.publicationDate.publicationDateId in (:publicationDateIdsList)
  and model.constituency.id = :id group by model.panchayat.panchayatId
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you show your sql?

Comment: 70 records? A long time? What are they? Movie files?

Comment: no no.Just 1,2,3,5,.....70

Comment: In general retrieving 70 objects at once work faster then 7 time 10 objects each time. The only case when you can gain in time - if you objects are too large and selecting them all together cause memory swaping, but I think it is not the case. So in general - you should do think like this only in two cases:

Comment: @Dmitry can u explain clearly.Is it not the right way

Comment: 1) You work with data like with a stream processing current element and removing it in order to prevent Out of memory error or memory swaping in database
2) You are going to show initial small result data set (which contains only 10 elements) and them asynchronously load all other elements whenever they will be avaliable.

Sorry hit enter in previos comment before finished.

Comment: @Dmitry no i need to use the result at a time.

Comment: @Dmitry is there any alternative solution for me

Comment: What's are real sizes of lists from which you try to select elements? whether they both about 70? And what is more important what's the size of result set?

Comment: i am using 2 tables which contains nearly 2,00,000 records and 20,00,000

Comment: I wasn't asking about what is the sizes of the tables. I was asking what are the real sizes of locationValues and publicationDateIdsList and what is the size of result set when don't use any splitting?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ArrayList#subList` is a very efficient operation. You can iterate over ranges of size 10:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dbList.size(); i += 10) {
   List<Long> sub = dbList.subList(i, Math.min(dbList.size(),i+10)));
   ... query ...
}
```

Comment: if my list contains only 65 records.is there any exception i will get likw arrayindexout of bounnds exception

Comment: `Math.min` should take care of the edge case.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (formerly [GS Collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections)) and change dbList to a MutableList or something similar, you can write:

```
MutableList<Long> dbList = ...;
RichIterable<RichIterable<Long>> chunks = dbList.chunk(10);
```

If you can't change the return type of dbList, you can wrap it in a ListAdapter.

```
RichIterable<RichIterable<Long>> chunks = ListAdapter.adapt(dbList).chunk(10);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Comment: I wish Eclipse Collections would replace JCL. Love the library! It would be nice to have a .take(10) that only returns a single RichIterable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method in the `List` interface to divide your list.

Answer (score 0):

In pure Java code it could be probably done:

```
int parts = list.size()/10;

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<parts; j++){
                Long l = list.get(j + i*j);
                // l do sth;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As d'alar'cop stated, I think it may be an issue with your SQL statement, rather than the list. But anyway, I would do something like this:

```
int i = 1;
List<Long> newList = new ArrayList<Long>();
for(Long item : dbList)
    {
        for (i <= 10; i++)
        {
            newList.Add(item)

            if (i == 10)
            {
                //SQL Statement
                i = 1;
            }

            break;
        }

    }
```

Or, a `subList` as the others have mentioned would work as well, and may be a more compact solution.

Comment: `==` not `=` for your if... that's also an infinite loop. I think what you're thinking of is looping through all of the items. ex for i < dbList when i is divisible by 10 execute sql

Comment: Good point. I fixed the `if` statement equality and I _think_ I fixed the infinite loop with `break`, but there's definitely a better way to do it.

Comment: Almost..... You need a counter to keep track of which item your on. right now it enters the `for each` then enters the next `for` that counts 10. Your counting 10 on one item adding 10 items to `newList` I would open up eclipse and actually step through your code bc your missing some key points.

Comment: My fault. I was thinking that `break` would be a quick way to get out of the for loop and go to the next item in the list.

Comment: Yea careful thought for program flow is very important, right now the code just populates `newList` with `dbList`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what are you trying to do, but you could try something like the following pseudocode, if you build your query with a loop anyway:

```
counter=0;
for (Long item : dbList){
    query.add (item);
    if (counter>10){
        query.send();
        counter=0;
    }
}
if (!query.empty())
    query.send();
```

This is just pseudocode. Probably you don't have a  query object like this, but is just to explain my point.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Simple Class which contains function to return 10 elements from list which having a start index.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestTenElement {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Getting all the element list from DB -- Here Creating Sample List
    List<Long> myList = new ArrayList<Long>();

    // Dummy element list
    for (long i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
        myList.add(i);
    }

    // Calling function may be from different class
    System.out.println(getFiveElement(myList, 0)); // First Ten Element from StartIndex 0
    System.out.println(getFiveElement(myList, 10)); // Second Ten Element from StartIndex 5
    // .......
    System.out.println(getFiveElement(myList, 50)); // If Last Iteration Gives remaining elements
}

// print ten element from list from the start index specified
public static List<Long> getFiveElement(List<Long> myList, int startIndex) {
    List<Long> sub = new ArrayList<Long>();

    sub = myList.subList(startIndex, Math.min(myList.size(), startIndex + 10));
    return sub;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet might be helpful.

```
     int pointer =0;
     List<Long> chunks = null;
     List<Long> longValues =    LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
     int limit =10;
     do{ 
             chunks = new ArrayList<>();
             for(int incrementor =pointer ; incrementor < longValues.size() && incrementor < pointer+limit; incrementor++){
                 chunks.add(longValues.get(incrementor));
             }
             if(chunks.size() == limit){
                 pointer = pointer + limit;
             }

             if(chunks.size() >0){
                 System.out.println(chunks);
             //your update query goes here
             }
     }while(chunks.size() ==limit);
```